# 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Windows' is undefined - Cordova Windows Phone App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, apache-cordova

I am using web context of windows and from my main index.html , I am opening map.html in iframe.

On the startup, it throws above error in cordova.js file.

My startup page : index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="app-wrapper">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-    scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for   JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for   TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of   XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
   -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'   data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src   *">

  <!-- Allow everything but only from the same origin and foo.com -->
  <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'  foo.com">-->

  <!-- This policy allows everything (eg CSS, AJAX, object, frame, media,  etc) except that
    * CSS only from the same origin and inline styles,
    * scripts only from the same origin and inline styles, and eval()
    -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-  src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

  <!-- Allows XHRs only over HTTPS on the same domain. -->
  <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'       https:">-->

  <!-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self';    frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">


  <!--materialize js-->
  <!--<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>-->
  <!-- app's js -->

  <!--<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js" rel="stylesheet" >    </script>-->
  <!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->

  <!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->


  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->




  <!--<script src="cordova.js"></script>-->


  <title></title>
  </head>

  <body >
   <!--<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>-->
   <!--<iframe id="Map" src="ms-appx-web:///www/map.html"  style="width:100%;height:500px;"></iframe>-->

   <x-ms-webview id="webview" src="ms-appx-web:///www/map.html" width="100%" height="300px"></x-ms-webview>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Then my map.html : page where I navigate from index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="app-wrapper">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <!-- Good default declaration:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
            * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->

    <!-- Allow everything but only from the same origin and foo.com -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">-->
    <!-- This policy allows everything (eg CSS, AJAX, object, frame, media, etc) except that
        * CSS only from the same origin and inline styles,
        * scripts only from the same origin and inline styles, and eval()
    -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">-->
    <!-- Allows XHRs only over HTTPS on the same domain. -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:">-->
    <!-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">-->


    <title></title>
   <script src="https://code.jquey.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!--fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft%3A400%2C500%2C700%2C400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material%20Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!--ionic css-->
    <!-- <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- overlay sidemenu css -->
    <link href="css/ionic.contrib.drawer.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--materialize css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
    <!--custom css-->
    <link href="css/angucomplete.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>


    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ionic.contrib.drawer.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <!--<script src="js/winstore-jscompat.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>-->

    <!--<script src="js/ionic.contrib.drawer.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>-->

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/angucomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>  




    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB6IssfON5a40fVqmubWL69haHn7O7j-Hs">
    </script>
    <!--<script src="js/angular-google-maps.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body id="Map" ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
</html>
```

I have error in cordova.js at below line :

```
 Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resumingHandler, false);
```

Comment: Hard to say without code posted, it sounds like you did not add the InAppBrower Plugin? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: I installed InAppBrowser but no help. Can you please check my code which I added in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting ng-cordova.min.js file before cordova.js. Cordova.js file should load at last.

Note : You will need to put your angular js file before above two as ng-cordova depends on angular.

And both the file should be in your startup html page only.